Position independent named arguments in a Rust macro
Background
I have a crate https://crates.io/crates/magic_migrate that provides a trait TryMigrate. I'm working on writing a macro that allows someone to define this trait by providing an error and a "chain" of structs that define a migration order. Eventually I would like to make an even-more generic macro that takes three things (error, deserializer, and struct chain).
Due to taking multiple different kinds of inputs, I would like it to have a keyword arg like syntax. For example:
 try_migrate_toml_chain!(
     error: PersonMigrationError,
     chain: [PersonV1, PersonV2],
 );

The issue I'm running into is that I have to re-define my macro to be position independent. Here's the code I came up with that works, but has duplication:
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! try_migrate_toml_chain {
    // Base case
    (error: $err:ident, chain: [$a:ident] $(,)?) => {
        impl TryMigrate for $a {
            type TryFrom = Self;
            type Error = $err;

            fn deserializer<'de>(input: &str) -> impl Deserializer<'de> {
                toml::Deserializer::new(input)
            }
        }
        impl From<Infallible> for $err {
            fn from(_value: Infallible) -> Self {
                unreachable!()
            }
        }
    };
    // Position variant
    (chain: [$a:ident], error: $err:ident $(,)?) => {
        $crate::try_migrate_toml_chain!(error: $err, chain: [$a]);
    };
    // Rest case
    (error: $err:ident, chain: [$a:ident, $($rest:ident),+] $(,)?) => (
        // Call the base case to link A => A
        $crate::try_migrate_toml_chain!(error: $err, chain: [$a]);

        // Link the rest i.e. A => B, B => C, etc.
        $crate::try_migrate_link!($a, $($rest),+);
    );
    // Position variant
    (chain: [$a:ident, $($rest:ident),+], error: $err:ident $(,)?) => (
        $crate::try_migrate_toml_chain!(error: $err, chain: [$a, $($rest),+])
    );
}

This works, but is quite verbose. It gets even more verbose with 3 arguments. This leads me to my question.
Question
Is there an easy(er) to define a macro so the keyword-ish inputs can be position independent than having to manually re-define the macro_rules! pattern with a different order?

You might want to look into The Little Book of Rust Macros for some common patterns. In particular, have a look at Incremental TT Munchers, which are quite expressive (but also note they might be bad for your compilation times).
In your case, I would suggest that you split your macro into the "invocation", as seen by the user, and the "internal state", as used by the macro in recursive calls. This internal state will look like @internal([ <error, if set> ], [ <chains, if set> ]). You can use tt repetitions to define which arguments have or have not been provided yet. Something like this:
macro_rules! try_migrate_toml_chain {
    // internal: base case
    (@internal([ $($error:tt)* ], [ $($chain:tt)* ]), []) => {
        println!("error arg was: {}", stringify!($($error)*));
        println!("chain arg was: {}", stringify!($($chain)*));
    };

    // internal: recursive cases
    (@internal([ $($error:tt)* ], [ $($chain:tt)* ]), [chain: [$new_chain:ident] $($rest:tt)*]) => {
        try_migrate_toml_chain!(@internal([$($error)*], [$new_chain]), [$($rest)*]);
    };
    (@internal([ $($error:tt)* ], [ $($chain:tt)* ]), [error: $new_error:ident $($rest:tt)*]) => {
        try_migrate_toml_chain!(@internal([$new_error], [$($chain)*]), [$($rest)*]);
    };
    (@internal([ $($error:tt)* ], [ $($chain:tt)* ]), [, $($rest:tt)*]) => {
        try_migrate_toml_chain!(@internal([$($error)*], [$($chain)*]), [$($rest)*]);
    };
    (@internal([ $($error:tt)* ], [ $($chain:tt)* ]), [$($rest:tt)*]) => {
        compile_error!("unexpected token");
    };

    // invocation
    ($($rest:tt)*) => {
        try_migrate_toml_chain!(@internal([], []), [$($rest)*]);
    };
}

fn main() {
    try_migrate_toml_chain!();
    try_migrate_toml_chain!(error: A);
    try_migrate_toml_chain!(chain: [C]);
    try_migrate_toml_chain!(error: A, chain: [C]);
    try_migrate_toml_chain!(chain: [C], error: A);
}

Note that there are several things you can change:

You can prevent duplicate arguments by checking if the internal state is currently [] for the given argument when it is provided.
You can make sure some arguments are "required" by checking that the internal state is not empty for them in the base case.
You can make some arguments append to the internal state instead of replacing it as in the example, which you might want for your chain setup.

To add more named arguments, you still need to expand the cases, namely to add the new value to the internal state, to be matched in all cases. However, since the macro now walks down the invocation one argument at a time, you do not need to consider all possible argument orders.
Finally, I think declarative macros make sense when the grammar is simple and easy to define in the grammar DSL. For more complex parsing such as this, you might want to reach for procedural macros instead.
